# Incorrect claim Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am currently working on an API.  The tokens are returned from an IdentityServer4.

I am trying to get back the sub id which is the id of the currently authorized user from the token claim.   I can see it in the Claim here.

```
{
  "nbf": 1512632838,
  "exp": 1512636438,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5000",
  "aud": [
    "http://localhost:5000/resources",
    "testapi"
  ],
  "client_id": "ServiceAccountAccess",
  "sub": "21248582",
  "auth_time": 1512632823,
  "idp": "local",
  "name": "TestUser",
  "resource_id": "21260601",
  "xena_fiscal_id": "21875",
  "fiscal_name": "My company",
  "picture_url": "/Content/images/avatar-company-xena.jpg",
  "application_id": "16140911",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "testapi"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "password"
  ]
}
```

My API call is quite simple

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeFiscal([FromBody] long fiscalId)
    {

        var name = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")
            .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

    }
```

What i cant understand is why sub or subject is being turned into

> "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"

[image]

I can see from the api that its done it to quite a few of the claims

```
{
  "nbf": 1512653706,
  "exp": 1512657306,
  "iss": "http://localhost:5000",
  "aud": [
    "http://localhost:5000/resources",
    "testapi"
  ],
  "client_id": "ServiceAccountAccess",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "21248582",
  "auth_time": 1512652100,
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider": "local",
  "name": "TestUser",
  "supporter": "21248582",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences": "password",
  "resource_id": "21527443",
  "xena_fiscal_id": "21876",
  "fiscal_name": "this",
  "picture_url": "/Content/images/avatar-company-xena.jpg",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "testapi"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Its taken an hour to figure out that the Microsoft JWT handler turns these standard claims into Microsoft proprietary ones.

By adding the following line to the startup Configure method i was able to turn off this annoying "feature"

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear()
```

Comment: I don't understand why more people didn't upvote this... Seems like everyone is happy with Microsoft propietary claims... Thanks a lot, @DaImTo, it really helped.

Comment: May have changed in newer versions but it is `DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap` that I had to use.